# How to correctly fetch String values from the database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For my website, when this particular page is clicked I want the form to be populated with data from the database. Here is the code for the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{url('/company-profile/update')}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        @foreach($getAllDetails as $list)
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label for="companyname" class="control-label">Company Name</label>  
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyname" name="companyname" placeholder="Enter Company Name" value={{$list->companyName}}>
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <label for="shortCode" class="control-label">Short Code</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="shortCode" name="shortCode" placeholder="Short Code" value={{$list->shortCode}}>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-7">
                    <label for="telnum" class="control-label">Telephone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telnum" name="telnum" placeholder="Tel. number" value={{$list->phoneNo}}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label for="emailid" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" value={{$list->emailAddress}}>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label for="logoPath" class="control-label">Logo Path</label>
                    <input type="" class="form-control" id="logoPath" name="logoPath" placeholder="Enter Logo Path" value={{$list->logoPath}}>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label for="feedback" class="control-label">Contact Address</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" rows="2" value={{$list->contactAddress}}></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
           @endforeach
             <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form>
```

This issue is:

For example, if I want to fetch the company name `{{$list->companyName}}` only the first word gets displayed. For example, If the company's name is National Film Institute, only National gets displayed.

Here is code the for my index function in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['getAllDetails']= DB::table('tblcompany')->get();
    return view('companyProfile.companyProfile', $data);
}
```

Comment: Can you pass `$data` to your view and read it with `foreach($getAllDetails as $list)`? Wondering if this is a typo or some magic PHP capability I didn't know about

Comment: Can you please show output of $getAllDetails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

> value={{$list->your_field}}
>   to

```
value="{{$list->your_field}}"
```